# If or CASE statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, case

I am trying to use if or case statement in mqsql.... here is my query

```
$db->query("SELECT 
keywords.keyword,
keywords.keyid,
sources.s_title,
sources.s_disc,
sources.sourceid,
sources.s_link
FROM link_ks
INNER JOIN keywords ON link_ks.keyid = keywords.keyid
INNER JOIN sources ON link_ks.sourceid = sources.sourceid
case when 
thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down != ''
then 
INNER JOIN thumbsup_items ON link_ks.sourceid = thumbsup_items.name
 else null
WHERE link_ks.keyid = :keyid
 order by 
if((thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) != '',
((thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) desc ,thumbsup_items.votes_up desc,sources.sourceid),
sources.sourceid )
");
```

I have used CASE and if Both is this query but nothing is working i know CASE and IF both are giving error but i dont know how to fix this ...

ERROR

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

*EDIT*
 My problem is this. if there is no vote this query dont give any output so i am using IF  statement

```
$db->query("SELECT 
keywords.keyword,
keywords.keyid,
sources.s_title,
sources.s_disc,
sources.sourceid,
sources.s_link
FROM link_ks
INNER JOIN keywords ON link_ks.keyid = keywords.keyid
INNER JOIN sources ON link_ks.sourceid = sources.sourceid
LEFT JOIN thumbsup_items ON thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down != '' AND link_ks.sourceid = thumbsup_items.name
WHERE link_ks.keyid = :keyid 
if((thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) != '',
(thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) desc ,
sources.sourceid )
");
```

Now Error in If statement ...
Please help

Comment: Are `votes_up` and `votes_down` numeric? Why are you comparing the sum with empty string `''`?

Comment: @AzizShaikh they are votes values in numbers ... if no one have given any vote it will be '' si i was looking for '' with if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the case inside the join condition, try this:

```
SELECT 
keywords.keyword,
keywords.keyid,
sources.s_title,
sources.s_disc,
sources.sourceid,
sources.s_link
FROM link_ks
INNER JOIN keywords ON link_ks.keyid = keywords.keyid
INNER JOIN sources ON link_ks.sourceid = sources.sourceid
LEFT JOIN thumbsup_items ON thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down != '' AND link_ks.sourceid = thumbsup_items.name
WHERE link_ks.keyid = :keyid
ORDER BY 
CASE
    WHEN (thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) != ''
    THEN (thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down)
    ELSE sources.sourceid
END DESC
```

Comment: Thx for reply ... its giving blank result ... as there is no votes so its giving blank result  ;(

Comment: @Harinder change `INNER JOIN thumbsup_items` to `LEFT JOIN thumbsup_items`

Comment: it worked ... now how can i do this in ORDER BY can i use if in ORDER BY ?

Comment: now Error in Order By IF statement ... i have edited above question ... thx for helping

Comment: @Harinder are you still using `IF`? Did you try the `ORDER BY` with `CASE` as in my answer?

Comment: Same error  right syntax to use near 'desc, thumbsup_items.votes_up desc ;(

Comment: if figer it out its ' desc,
        thumbsup_items.votes_up desc,' i have to remove and END DESC Thx for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `case` or `if` to decide whether to include a `join` or not. Instead run the rest of the query with other joins and on the result set, use filter condition for the desired result.

In a `SELECT` statement, `IF` and `CASE` can only be used post joining of tables or views on columns or expressions. But you can't frame statement with a condition like

```
JOIN (CASE WHEN condition THEN this ELSE that END)
```